# t-test equal variances, unequal small sample size, not normal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, normality-assumption

I have two independent groups. Group 1 with 16 samples and group 2 with 10 samples. I want to know if the means are statistically different so I was thinking of a t-test for 2 means for equal variances. To test for variance I run a Levene test and result a p value of 0.45.

When I do anderson-darling for normality with all the data it has a p value of 0.012 which is not normal. But when i test group 1 and group 2 **separatelly** the anderson-darling test indicates normallity for both.

Should I change tests or is ok testing normallity separatelly?

Comment: Isn't the Levene test is used for equality of variances, not equality of means? The results of your test indicate that, most likely, they have the same variance; if you think that they also have the same mean and that both are normal, I think you can use the normality test on the pooled data. If any of those two things fail, test for normality separately.

Comment: Apparent normality of the data really, really does not matter (despite what many people will insist).  What *does* matter is in what way the data depart from being Normal.  Although the AD test is one way to measure that, it's not directly relevant to assessing the t-test.  One of the best ways to approach this is to inspect graphical depictions of the data distributions.  You should be concerned mostly about strong amounts of skewness or obviously outlying values.

Comment: If you combine the two samples into one, you're looking at a mixture of two distributions; there's no relevant assumption in any sense of the word about that. If you want to examine more than one group together (given that you expect the means to differ), you'd look at aggregating residuals rather than observations.